# Clientside video concatenation

Tags: video, video-streaming, html5-video

Video is often sent as chunks which are then combined together in a player clientside to seemlessly play a video. I was wondering if it's possible to do something similar (ideally clientside) with sequential videos, basically concatenating them into a single video from a list of several urls, all to seemlessly play in one embedded movie player?

As it exists on many websites, it seems like many versions of a video at different resolutions are saved and then chunks are sent from different sources depending on the resolution settings to a client, and these files are interchangeably referenced. Compared to that, it seems like it'd be easier to be able to concatenate several videos, which each one in a way acting as its own chunk/chapter.

Comment: It'd be far easier to juggle multiple video elements.  And then, you have choices over how/where to display them in the UI as well.

Comment: @Skyler **(1)** In general yes, it's possible to join several videos as one. You have to decide which video format you want to process and then read up on its file (byte) structure. **(2)** Generally you get the first file's header and adjust it to account for the new frames (coming from all next videos) and also skip the headers from the other files (you want to extract only the frames when joining) to make your final output video.